# Fetching size of object's list - Optional.get() without .ifPresent

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have method that return `Optional` of Book object (do not mind with names as it is just a sample of code). I want to fetch the size of list which is inside Book class:

```
public class Book {
    Integer b;

    DateTime dateOfCreation;

    Integer a;

    List<Integer> bookList;
}
```

So it goes like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Optional<Book> book = getBookObject();
        int sizeOfList = book.get().bookList.size();
    }

    static Optional<Book> getBookObject() {
        return Optional.of(new Book());
    }
}
```

I have warning within the `get()` which goes like `Optional.get() without .ifPresent` what is the proper approach to fetch this size of the list?

Comment: Why are you using optional as return type here?

Comment: @Sneh it's a sample code, I've bigger project which I thought it is not necessary to paste it here. Just give you an analogy.

Comment: Makes sense, look into orElseThrow and orElse

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko I was already there it didn't help me as I do not need to perform any action when object is null. Just want to fetch

Comment: @mara122 Please, read the links I included more thoroughly. 3 of them discuss `ifPresent`, and when/how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to avoid using `Optional.get()` directly as using it directly might throw `NoSuchElementException`:

```
book.ifPresent(b -> {
   int  sizeOfList = b.bookList.size();
   // do stuff with sizeOfList
});
```

The above code uses a `Consumer` callback to get the unwrapped `Book` object and use it.

The second one is to use, Optional.isPresent() which returns `true` if some value is present else it will return `false`:

```
int sizeOfList = book.isPresent() ? book.get().bookList.size() : 0;
```

We could also use `Optional.orElse(otherValue)` the `otherValue` is returned if the `Optional` is empty:

```
int sizeOfList = book.orElse(new Book()).bookList.size();
```

As per @Holger we could use `Optional.map()` to map it to the `Optional<Integer>` and return 0 with `orElse()` if the `Optional` was empty:

```
int sizeOfList = book.map(b -> b.bookList.size()).orElse(0);
```

Comment: You cannot make this way with `orElse()` as I got now: `orElse(List<Integer) cannot be applied to (int)`

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick I downvoted because you answered a duplicate. With the latest update, your answer is incorrect. `.map(Book::getBookList)` returns an `Optional<List<Integer>>`, so a `List<Integer>` is excepted at `orElse` (not an `int`). It should not compile.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I will correct it.

Comment: @mara122 please check now, but make sure the `bookList` list is not null otherwise you would get a NPE.

Answer (score -1):

To obtain an optional containing the size or an empty optional if the book is not present:

```
Optional<Integer> sizeOfListOptional = book.map((Book presentBook) -> presentBook.bookList.size());
```

Comment: it's a duplicate, and it should be closed as one (I downvoted)

Comment: So is there a reason you don't close it and instead lecture other posters?

Comment: i haven't found any proper answer for my question,that's why I asked the question.

Comment: @Smutje but it is necessary to store it size as an Optiomal? Cannot have primitive tpye?

Comment: The warning says it all: As you have an optional it is not safe that the value is present and you need to be able to treat both cases - that's why mapping into an optional is safe and accessing the value otherwise is not.